# Disable remembering WiFi password

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, password

Edit: This is **not** asking how to get Ubuntu to remember WiFi passwords. I'm asking for the opposite.

Most of the other questions I find ask how to get Ubuntu's NetworkManager to *stop forgetting* the WiFi password. Instead, here I'm wondering how to *get* it to forget the password each time. That is, for security purposes, I would like it so that I would manually need to choose a WiFi network *and* enter its password each time I start Ubuntu and login. I already know how to get it to stop automatically connecting to a network, but not how to get it to be amnestic about passwords.

Comment: The only way to do it is to remove the network from its configuration (with `nm-connection-manager` hopefully, since that's the most robust of the config manager tools for Network Manager) after use of the network.  There's no way to reconfigure network manager to not by-default remember the wifi password, currently.